# AWS EFS File Sync between Regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-efs

Has someone configured EFS File Sync to copy files from one EFS in one Region to another EFS in another Region?

Does the origin EC2 (where the sync agent is located) have to be reachable from the Internet? Or does it have to have Internet access through a NAT Instance/Gateway?

Does the destination EFS have to be reachable from the Internet?

Thanks.